# WooCommerce Adding multiple items to the cart with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I use latest version of Wordpress and Woocommerce. I have some JavaScript that loops over DOM elements of class `.selectable` and grabs the `product_id` attribute from the ones with class `.selected`, and adds that item to the cart:

```
// selects the elements
$('.next').on('click', function() {
    var parent  = $(this).closest('.panel');
    var selectables = parent.children('.option.selectable.selected');

    $(selectables).each(function() {
        var product = $(this).attr('product');
        add_to_cart(product, 1);    
    });
}

// add to cart AJAX
function add_to_cart(product_id, qty) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {action : 'cl_add_to_cart', 'product_id': product_id, 'qty': qty},
        success : function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

And I have a PHP function in functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_cl_add_to_cart', 'cl_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cl_add_to_cart', 'cl_add_to_cart');

function cl_add_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $product_id   = trim($_POST['product_id']);
    $qty = !empty($_POST['qty']) ? trim($_POST['qty']) : 1;
    $added = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $qty);
    echo json_encode($added);
}
```

The AJAX call is hitting the PHP function just fine - I can echo out $added which gives me a hash. If I have two or more items in the selectables var, they both hit the PHP function (I get two hashes back) but only the first one gets added to the cart.

I can't for the life of me figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: I tested your code and it's working fine for me. are you sure you are not adding the same product each time because if you are adding same product to cart then it will be increase the quantity of that product not will consider as new product.

Answer (score 3):

Is better to send all items to be added all together at once with Ajax, than send them separately in multiple Ajax requests, this will be lighter and more effective.

You need to be sure that `$(selectables).each(function() { // ... });` is working as you expect.

The following will send a unique Ajax request for your click event.

The jQuery code

```js
// Multi Ajax adda to cart
function multiAddToCart( productsData ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            'action': 'multi_add_to_cart',
            'items' : Object.assign({}, productsData)
        },
        success : function(response) {
            $(document.body).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh'); // Refresh cart fragments
            console.log(response);
        },
        error : function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}

$('.next').on('click', function() {
    var productsData = [];
    var parent  = $(this).closest('.panel');
    var selectables = parent.children('.option.selectable.selected');

    $(selectables).each(function() {
        var productId = $(this).attr('product');
        productsData.push({'id': productId, 'qty': 1});
    });
    // Check the data before (number of items found)
    console.log(productsData); 

    multiAddToCart( productsData );
});
```

The php receiver function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_multi_add_to_cart', 'multi_ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_multi_add_to_cart', 'multi_ajax_add_to_cart');
function multi_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    if (isset($_POST['items']) ) {
        $item_keys = array();

        foreach( $_POST['items'] as $item ) {
            if( isset($item['id']) ) {
                $item_qty  = isset($item['qty']) && $item['qty'] > 1 ? $item['qty'] : 1;
                $item_keys[] = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($item['id'], $item_qty);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($item_keys); // Send back cart item keys
    }
    die();
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

It should work adding all items at once.

Comment: Okay, thank you. The difference is there are multiple next buttons, like 8, so I will need to abstract productsData outside the click event so it persists.

Answer (score 0):

The main answer does not really address the underlying problem. Plus it is not always possible to add the products at the same time. You may have an order form where the user can click quickly on multiple different items.

Here's the problem:
The WooCommerce add to cart function works by setting the `$this->cart_contents` variable to specific items.

The problem occurs when you use `WC()->cart->add_to_cart()` in AJAX, because multiple such add_to_cart functions are running concurrently. What happens is that one function will start after the previous function started but did not finish.

The result is that the 2nd function sets the cart content, without knowing it's missing the products the previous function just added.

Now the solution: Make the javascript wait until the previous function finished with a recursive function:

(this code is not complete, it just illustrates the idea):

```
add_cart_clear = 'yes';

function order_form_add(datavar, qty){

    if (add_cart_clear === 'yes'){ // proceed only if clear
        
        add_cart_clear = 'no'; // new function started, not clear
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){ // function ended, it's clear again
            add_cart_clear = 'yes';                             
        });

    } else {

        setTimeout(function(){
            order_form_add(data, qty); // if not ready, wait 100ms and try again
        }, 100);
    }
    
}
```