# WooCommerce: Add multiple cross-sell products to the cart at once with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

On my product detail page I'm trying to allow users to add multiple cross-sell products to the cart at once.

I found a few examples how this could be done. But most of them work with URL parameters.
For my case I'm trying to do this with ajax. Like the default add-to-cart button.

On my research I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66765723/1788961).

But I'm not sure how to adapt it for my case.
At the moment I have a list of product ID's from a custom loop.

Here's my custom loop code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_cols_before', 'show_cross_sell_in_single_product', 1200);
function show_cross_sell_in_single_product(){
    $crosssells = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_crosssell_ids',true);
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'product',
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'post__in'          => $crosssells,
        'tax_query'     => array(
          array(
              'relation' => 'OR',
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                  'field'    => 'name',
                  'terms'    => 'exclude-from-catalog',
                  'operator' => 'NOT IN',
              ),
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                  'field'    => 'name',
                  'terms'    => 'exclude-from-catalog',
                  'operator' => '=',
              ),
          )
      ),
        );
    $products_crosssells = new WP_Query( $args );
    $products_crosssells_ids = wp_list_pluck( $products_crosssells->posts, 'ID' );
    if( $products_crosssells->have_posts() ) :  ?>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <?php while ( $products_crosssells->have_posts() ) : $products_crosssells->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product-crosssells' ); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            <a href="">Add all to the cart</a>
        </div>

    <?php endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

The product ID's are stored in `$products_crosssells_ids`.

As I understand the example from the link above, I need to add the product ID's to the custom function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_multi_add_to_cart', 'multi_ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_multi_add_to_cart', 'multi_ajax_add_to_cart');
function multi_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    if (isset($_POST['items']) ) {
        $item_keys = array();

        foreach( $_POST['items'] as $item ) {
            if( isset($item['id']) ) {
                $item_qty  = isset($item['qty']) && $item['qty'] > 1 ? $item['qty'] : 1;
                $item_keys[] = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($item['id'], $item_qty);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($item_keys); // Send back cart item keys
    }
    die();
}
```

But I'm not sure how I need to add/adapt this code to my product page.

So A user could click on this link and adds everything to the cart:

`<a href="">Add all to the cart</a>`

Comment: the function you shared is using a `$_POST` so you may have to use a form with post method instead of a link, you populate with hidden fields and use a button to submit

Comment: you have to pay attention to the multiAddToCart function in the example you gave